# Reputation by Region

Tags: feature-request

The company I work for currently has a dedicated recruiter on board. I've heard indirectly that he managed to perform a search combining a skill (C#) and StackOverflow reputation. I came 3rd highest in the surrounding area. I'm not actually sure how he performed the search but my reaction was "that's great - who's beating me?".

So in the gamification sprit it would be great if we could see reputation by different granularity of areas. This would also feed really well into Careers, possibly encourage meet ups for certain things (eg technologies based on tags).

I might flesh this out more tomorrow when I'm in front of a PC.

Comment: Have you taken a look at SEDE? I remember some query specifically for this in there.

Comment: I did, but it's not robust enough. E.g - "UK", " United Kingdom", "England", " Great Britain". I'm thinking something more reliable and built into the system ideally

Comment: It's a bit tough to identify the entirety of all users from regions, especially if they don't self-report where they are.

Answer (score 2):

This is a nice idea.

But there are a lot of problems about this idea. First, security reasons. Kids (which are also SE users like me) were taught never to give out our location at the very least and seemingly a lot of people follow that rule. I'm on the moon, some people are some place where it is not on Earth or does not exist. With like a million plus locations possible (I'm exaggerating), this might not be so good. I mean, who would want to be first place in an area where only you or some other dozen people exist in?

How many regions? We are international and there so many places you could be right now. I mean how do we separate the areas? By country, population, continent, size, what factor is needed to determine what a region is? There are lots of questions and at the very least, we could try making leader-boards for every continent (if you set it to Antarctica, you better be a penguin).

Other than that, it should motivate some of our low-ranked users. It would be better to see something like `Top 10% in United States` rather than `Top 50% Overall`. The percentage can be a factor whether a user wants to really compete and thus contribute more to the community. This should add more traffic and users. We could even add little compeitions for each region!

Comment: Thanks for your points. I understand your concern from a child safeguarding perspective, although there shouldn't be anyone under 13 using the stackexchange network. It could be made an opt-in idea or it could be collected automatically but published in a way such that you can only see people within a region (rather than which region a person resides in). It probably just needs a little thought. I'd say Regions should be scaled to be useful - eg, UK is kinda useful for me, the county I'm in is even better, and the City is great for me to market myself should I ever wish to do so.